# "$f(x)$ decays AT LEAST as $1/x$: Is this Big-Oh notation or Little-oh notation rather?

Tags: asymptotics

If I want to show that, as $x\to x_0$, the function $f(x)$ decreases to some value at least as fast as $1/x$, is this saying that one wants to show that $f(x)\in O(1/x)$ as $x\to x_0$?

Or does the "at least" rather mean the little-oh idea, i.e. $f(x)\in o(1/x)$ as $x\to x_0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“At least” means non-strict inequality ($\le$) so it means Big Oh ($\mathcal{O}$).